# NServiceBus, Subscribe by interface when there are multiple interfaces

Tags: c#, nservicebus

With NServiceBus you can subscribe by interface, eg:

```
public class MyEvent: ISomeInterface {}

public class Handler: IHandleMessages<ISomeInterface>{...}
```

This all seems to work happily, however when you have multiple interfaces eg:

```
public class MyEvent: ISomeInterface, ISomeOtherInterface {}

public class Handler: IHandleMessages<ISomeInterface>{/*Works fine*/}

public class Handler: IHandleMessages<ISomeOtherInterface>{/*Doesnt work*/}
```

When using pub/sub the message is correctly subscribed to in either case, but when the message is actually published the receiving service errors with:

> No handlers could be found for message type: ISomeInterface

It appears to only work if the interface you are handling is the first on the sent message class. If I swap the order of interfaces on the actual event implementation around the second handler works fine but the first errors with a similar message (ie order of interfaces is whats causing the issue)

**Is there some way to handle messages by interface no matter what order the interfaces were in when the message was constructed?**

I've tried this with the handler using NSB 3 and NSB 4 both produce the same result.

**EDIT:**

As requested heres a more detailed snippet of the subscriber config I am using. I've also put together a minimal repro pub/sub app to demonstrate the issue I'm having ([on github here](https://github.com/lukemcgregor/NServiceBusMultipleInterfaces)).

```
Configure.Features.Disable<NServiceBus.Features.TimeoutManager>().Disable<NServiceBus.Features.SecondLevelRetries>();
Configure.With()
    .DefineEndpointName("nsbinterfaces.subscriber")
    .DefiningEventsAs(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.Contains(".Events"))
    //.NinjectBuilder(kernel)
    .DefaultBuilder()
    .UseTransport<Msmq>()
        .PurgeOnStartup(false)
    .MsmqSubscriptionStorage("nsbinterfaces.subscriber")
    .UnicastBus()
        .LoadMessageHandlers()
        .ImpersonateSender(false)
    .CreateBus()
    .Start(
        () => Configure.Instance.ForInstallationOn<NServiceBus.Installation.Environments.Windows>().Install());
```

Comment: Which container are you using?  Seems very likely that it has to do with container automatic registration.

Comment: @PhilSandler Im using the NServicebus.Ninject adapter, ill try swapping it out for something else on Monday and see if that sorts it out. It *should* just work in this use case shouldn't it? I'm not missing some good this isn't allowed?

Comment: Can you share the code to reproduce this?

Comment: @SeanFarmar see my edit + example repro solution

Comment: @PhilSandler I tried also with the default builder and it seemed not to help. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question in the NSB forums and its been converted to an issue, which looks like it should be resolved in v5 of the software. (https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues/2301)

Until its fixed I think there's 2 options:

- Send it as 2 separate messages
- Put the implementation into the published library (Thanks @seanfarmar)

Answer (score 2):

After looking at the repro, I think I know what's going on.

Your Publisher knows about it's own event (MyEvent) and two interfaces that it implements.  The two interfaces are in an assembly that is shared.

Your subscriber knows nothing about MyEvent, so it doesn't know that it implements both interfaces.  It's either an ISomeInterface or an ISomeOtherInterface, so it deserializes it to *one* of those types.

Since the order of the interface seems to dictate what type of message it is received as, I would guess that NSB will deserialize the message to the first type it sees that it knows about (per process).

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Messages xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"    
     xmlns="http://tempuri.net/NsbInterfaces.Publisher.Events" 
     xmlns:baseType="NsbInterfaces.Events.ISomeInterface" 
     xmlns:baseType1="NsbInterfaces.Events.ISomeOtherInterface">    
    <MyEvent></MyEvent>
    </Messages>
```

Comment: I think this is probably right but shouldn't it deserialise to all types it has handlers for?

Comment: I'm not sure--I always tend to handle the concrete type, so this has never come up for me.  Interestingly, if you add a reference to the publisher, and add handlers for both interfaces and the concrete type, they all get hit.  This might be a good question for the particular support forum (google groups).

Comment: Thanks, ill post it over there and see what they say.

Comment: Luke, I've raised an issue for this.  For more details, please see:
https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues/2301

Answer (score 1):

You need to move you interface implementation to the shared assembly (NsbInterfaces.Events)

[Added a pull request to you repo](https://github.com/lukemcgregor/NServiceBusMultipleInterfaces/pull/1)

HTH

Comment: Yeah this works but in my real application I really need to just publish the individual interfaces not their collection together, so unfortunately this isn't going to solve it for me.

Comment: If MyEvent is in NsbInterfaces.Events, subscribers can couple to the interfaces rather than MyEvent.